# How to add column to hive table which is already partitioned without using CASCADE?

Tags: hive

CASCADE option is only available in latest version, what is the approach to add column to hive table which is already partitioned.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question with sample query example ?

Comment: Hi Amby , more information is required , lets start with Hive version, table type External/Managed ? . Whether you intend to add column before or after partition column ! Does the table use AVRO schema file ! . If feasible you could move data to another external table temporarily , drop the existing table or recreate it with appropriate column placements and reload this table from the temporarily table, but if you are going down this path then make sure you have done the impact analysis as dropping and recreating invalidate metadata and some down stream applications might just get affected.

Comment: Hi, I am using External Table and it stores .csv file.  Add the new column at the end of existing column.